# Finding Sibling Node By Name

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, iis, iis-7

I am reading the applicationHost.xml.config file for IIS.  I am getting the Virtual Directories of EACH Site in Sites and then getting the information I need from that point. Information like the physical path and path. ***Then I need to get the the Bindings.***

I cannot figure out how to effectively get to the "Bindings" element node, when I have TWO application nodes. *(An example of this is shown below)* However, I CAN use "site.ParentNode.NextSibling.ChildNodes" which gets me a list of the respective bindings IF there is ONE application node.

Thanks in advance for your help!

**My Code:**

```
XDocument.Load(@"C:\\windows\\system32\\inetsrv\\config\\applicationHost.config");
XmlNodeList siteList = XDocument.SelectNodes("/configuration/system.applicationHost/sites/site/application/virtualDirectory");

foreach (XmlNode site in siteList)
{
    XmlAttribute XmlAttributeParentParentName = (XmlAttribute)site.ParentNode.ParentNode.Attributes.GetNamedItem("name");
    XmlAttribute XmlAttributePath = (XmlAttribute)site.Attributes.GetNamedItem("path");
    XmlAttribute XmlAttributePhysicalPath = (XmlAttribute)site.Attributes.GetNamedItem("physicalPath");
    XmlNodeList BindingList = (XmlNodeList)site.ParentNode.NextSibling.ChildNodes;

    string path = XmlAttributePath.Value.ToString();
    string siteName = XmlAttributeParentParentName.Value.ToString();
    string physicalPath = XmlAttributePhysicalPath.Value.ToString();
    string firstBindingElement = BindingList[0].Attributes.GetNamedItem("bindingInformation").Value.ToString();

    //do something with the variables.
    //rest of code is here
}
```

**Here is an example of a Site node:**

```
<site name="Site Name" id="20" serverAutoStart="true">
  <application path="/" applicationPool="SiteAppPool">
      <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SiteName" />
  </application>
  <application path="/store" applicationPool="SiteAppPool">
      <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SiteName\store" />
  </application>
  <bindings>
      <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:sitename.com" />
  </bindings>
</site>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm not missing something here, but couldn't you use SelectNodes on your iterated XmlNode like so:

```
XmlNodeList BindingList = (XmlNodeList)site.SelectNodes("../../bindings/binding");
```

This should take you from the root of your iteration node (which is the virtualDirectory node) to its parent (which is an application node) to its parent (which is the site node) down to the bindings node and finally to a list of binding nodes within this?